# Why is my update in my plugin on my custom entity not occurring?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm writing an auto number plugin for MS Dynamics CRM 2015. It works on the creation of an opportunity, when a new number needs to be generated. The current number is stored in another entity, which is retrieved at the time of creating the opportunity and then adds 1. The auto number entity is then updated with the new number (except it isn't as this isn't working at the moment).

At the moment the number is retrieved and 1 is added to it and is used in the opportunity correctly. However, as the update to the auto number entity does not occur when another opportunity is created it gets the same number as the previous one.

Here's my plugin code so far:

```
protected void ExecuteGenerateOpportunityAutoNumber(LocalPluginContext localContext)
{
    if (localContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("localContext");
    }

    IPluginExecutionContext context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
    IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;

    if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
    {
        Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

        if (entity.LogicalName == OPPORTUNITY_ENTITY_NAME)
        {
            if (!entity.Attributes.Contains(OPPORTUNITY_REF_ID))
            {
                try
                {
                    string newId = RetrieveAndUpdateLastId(service);
                    entity.Attributes.Add(OPPORTUNITY_REF_ID, newId);
                }
                catch (FaultException ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("GenerateOpportunityAutoNumber plugin error: ", ex);
                    //tracingService.Trace("GenerateOpportunityAutoNumber plugin error: {0}", ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The RetrieveAndUpdateLastId method code is below:

```
private string RetrieveAndUpdateLastId(IOrganizationService service)
{
    lock (lastIdentifierLock)
    {
        string result = null;

        ColumnSet cols = new ColumnSet();
        cols.AddColumns(LAST_REF_LAST_VALUE, LAST_REF_PRIMARY_KEY);

        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
        query.ColumnSet = cols;
        query.EntityName = LAST_REF_ENTITY_NAME;

        EntityCollection ec = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

        if (ec.Entities.Count >= 1)
        {
            foreach (Entity identifier in ec.Entities)
            {
                if (identifier.Attributes.Contains(LAST_REF_LAST_VALUE))
                {
                    int? lastValue = identifier[LAST_REF_LAST_VALUE] as int?;
                    if (lastValue != null)
                    {
                        string newValue = (lastValue.Value + 1).ToString().PadLeft(7, '0');

                        result = String.Format("SN{0}", newValue); //This is clearly happening as I'm getting the next number back.

                        identifier[LAST_REF_LAST_VALUE] = lastValue.Value + 1;

                        //Tried this also:
                        //identifier.Attributes.Remove(LAST_REF_LAST_VALUE);
                        //identifier.Attributes.Add(LAST_REF_LAST_VALUE, lastValue.Value + 1);

                        service.Update(identifier); //This doesn't seem to be happening.
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

No error is thrown but the update of the auto number just isn't happening. I've checked the user I'm running this as has the required update privileges on the auto number entity as well. Any ideas?

***UPDATE***

After debugging I found that it was throwing an error that the Principal user is missing the prvWrite privilege. This would explain why the update isn't happening, but now raises another issue. I've setup the plugin to run as a specific user (one with the correct privileges), but the Guid of the 'Principal user' in the error was of the calling user. Why would it run as the calling user when I've set it up to use a specific user?

***UPDATE 2***

I think I may have found the issue but wonder if anyone else can confirm / shed some more light on this. It seems that according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334744.aspx), the issue may lie with the user not being in a specific AD group, specifically

> User account (A) needs the privilege prvActOnBehalfOfAnotherUser,
>   which is included in the Delegate role.
>
> Alternately, for Active Directory directory service deployments only,
>   user account (A) under which the impersonation code is to run can be
>   added to the PrivUserGroup group in Active Directory. This group is
>   created by Microsoft Dynamics CRM during installation and setup. User
>   account (A) does not have to be associated with a licensed Microsoft
>   Dynamics CRM user. However, the user who is being impersonated (B)
>   must be a licensed Microsoft Dynamics CRM user.

For my purposes I think the user I'm trying to run as needs to be in PrivUserGroup in AD (which it's not), otherwise it defaults to the calling user.

***UPDATE 3***

I've been able to identify 2 fundamental problems. The first is as explained above, in that the context always runs as the calling user. The 2nd is that when either giving the calling user system admin privileges OR creating the IOrganizationService with a null parameter it still doesn't update. HOWEVER, and this seems very odd, these 2 scenarios DO work when profiling the plugin. Why would this be?

***UPDATE 4***

It seems I may have resolved the issue, though I'm not certain (hence why I've not written an answer as yet). As per the documentation we've added the user to be impersonated into the PrivUserGroup. The plugin now works. However, I don't understand why this is needed. Also, is this best practice in this scenario or have I done something that should never be done?

On a related note I also unregistered the plugin before deploying it this time, so I'm now wondering if this solved this issue. To confirm I've now removed the user from the PrivUserGroup in AD, but this takes some time (not sure exactly how long) to filter through apparently. If it still works then it looks like this actually resolved it. Do you normally need to unregister a plugin before re-deploying it to make sure it works?

***UPDATE 5***

Ok, so this if my final update. I'm not marking this as the answer as I'm not 100% certain, but it appears that removing the assembly using the plugin registration tool may have done the trick. From everything I've read you shouldn't need to unregister a plugin to redeploy, so my perhaps my assembly was corrupt somehow and by removing it and creating it again using the new assembly solve the issue. Unfortunately I don't have the original assembly to test with.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to debug your plugin. Following article contains a video that describes how to debug plugins using Plugin Debugger and Plugin Regitration Tool - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/devkeydet/archive/2015/02/17/debug-crm-online-plugins.aspx

***Updated*** How to have 2 instances of IOrganizationService for user context and system:

1. Open Plugin.cs file.
2. Locate following code:

   ```
   internal IOrganizationService OrganizationService
   {
       get;

       private set;
   }
   ```
3. Add following code after:

   ```
   internal IOrganizationService SystemOrganizationService
   {
       get;

       private set;
   }
   ```
4. Find following code:

   ```
       // Use the factory to generate the Organization Service.
       this.OrganizationService = factory.CreateOrganizationService(this.PluginExecutionContext.UserId);
   ```
5. Add following code after:

   this.SystemOrganizationService = factory.CreateOrganizationService(null);
6. Use this instance of IOrganizationService in the place where you need higher level of privileges.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll give it a go. My suspicion is that there's something wrong with how the auto number entity has been setup. Perhaps it's not updatable.

Comment: I've now found the root of the issue, but not fixed it. Can you take a look at my update?

Comment: You should go other way. Instead of trying of run plugin in the context of other user try to instantiate IOrganization using null parameter instead of UserId.

Comment: What benefit does this have? Why would instantiating the IOrganization service with a null UserId give me the correct privileges?

Comment: null parameter will give you highest rights - system level so any call to CRM would not be blocked from point of rights e.t.c.

Comment: Sounds like I need to instantiate the IOrganizationService at the individual plugin level and not in the autogenerated Plugin class. At the moment the generated Plugin class creates the IOrganization service with PluginExecutionContext.UserId. If I change this to null it would mean all plugins inheriting from that class would run with highest privileges, which doesn't sound right. Presumably I need to remove this from the generated class. Doesn't sound particularly scalable. That would mean every new plugin would need to duplicate code as there's no service instantiation in the base class.

Comment: There is possibility to create another one instance of IOrganizationService in your base Plugin class.

Comment: When creating a new plugin against an entity (using a Dynamics template) it gives the option of specifying who you want the plugin to run as, which I set as System Administrator. Is this effectively ignored then?

Comment: Could you take a look at my update and let me know your thoughts?

Comment: I suggest you easier way and if you don't want to follow my suggestion I can't help you.

Comment: I understand your alternative, and thank you for suggesting it, but I don't think this works very well for scalability. If I'm creating a plugin project, which will have multiple plugins and 1 base Plugin class, I think plugin specific code should sit within the plugin. Fundamentally I'm trying to understand why it doesn't operate using the User Context. If you don't know that's fine, just thought you may be able to help. I think I've managed to narrow it down anyway.

Comment: Updated my answer with code. I hope now it would be clearer what I've meant. You "issues with scalability" are fixed.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Makes much more sense now, though I still wonder if this needs to be done if I get the user I want to run it as in the correct AD group. Good work around though.

Comment: I try to avoid that impersonation because of environment-specific configurations. Obviously user ids would be different for your dev/stage/prod orgs so I try to avoid it as much as I can.

Comment: Apologies for removing this as the correct answer but I've only just been able to get back to this project. Your suggestion seemed to initially work, but on further investigation it only worked when profiling the plugin. When running normally, without profiling, it didn't update.

Comment: That's weird. This approach I use in my plugins and I haven't seen any weird results as you...